# Redirect to appstore in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, launch

I try to launch a link in my apps, so when user click the button it will redirect to appstore. Here is part of the code:

```
 InkWell(
                                onTap: () =>launchapp(),
                                child: Text(
                                        "Update",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 17),
                                      )
                              )

launchapp() async {
    try {
      if (await canLaunch('https://apps.apple.com/app/MyAppName/idXXXXX')) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I have tried it in my simulator, but always getting

```
safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid
```

is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Store_redirect package.

```
StoreRedirect.redirect(androidAppId: "com.iyaffle.rangoli",
                    iOSAppId: "585027354");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change DNS server and select manually option. Go to Apple menu then go to System Preferences > Network.
some of google Public DNS server example::
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
I had same issue solved this way.

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in AndroidManifest.xml just above of application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

***MobileUrl***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    
    class MobileUrl extends StatelessWidget {
      const MobileUrl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
      void  launchapp() async {
          final Uri url = 
         Uri.parse('https://apps.apple.com/app/MyAppName/idXXXXX');
          try {
            if (await canLaunch(url.toString())) {
              await launch(url.toString());
            } else {
              throw 'Could not launch $url';
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        }
    
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                
   
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                    launchapp();
                  }, child: Text('Launch app Button'))
    
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, as I know AndroidManifest.xml only configure for android apps, while I open the link from simulator xcode

Comment: use this dependencie => url_launcher: ^6.1.4
And below function :

 void launchapp1() async {
      final Uri url = Uri.parse('http://market.android.com/details?id=com.imangi.templerun&hl=en');
      try {
        if (await launchUrl(url,mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication)) {
          await launchUrl(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }

Comment: I am currently using url_launcher: ^6.0.20

Comment: this will use in redirect in app store : 
mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication

Answer (score 0):

```
launchapp() async {
    try {
      if (await canLaunch("https://apps.apple.com/app/id$appId")) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

`$appId` is your appId of App Store.

Comment: I have tried it and I still get ```safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid``` is it because I open it in simulator ?

Comment: Check `https://www.imyfone.com/iphone-issues/safari-cannot-open-the-page-address-is-invalid/` to try clearing data or rebooting your device.